# Finding a field extension in which every element has zero trace

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, vector-fields, trace

Let F be a field extension of K, then F over K is a vector space, and for each a in F define f:F-->F as f(x)=ax, this is a linear transformation, define trace of a as trace of this linear transformation. If K has characteristic zero then clear 1 has trace n, which is non zero. Are there fields F and K as above, such that every element of F has zero trace.

Comment: As you've noted the only place to look is degree p (or a multiple) extensions in characteristic p. Looking up some results on purely inseparable extensions might help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F=\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ and $K=\Bbb{F}_p(x^p)$. A basis of the extension $F/K$
consists of $1,x,\ldots,x^{p-1}$. The element $1$ has $tr^F_K(1)=0$ because the
$p\times p$ identity matrix has trace zero. The element $x^i, i=1,2,\ldots,p-1$, has
trace zero because its minimal polynomial $m_i(T)$ over $K$ is
$$(T-x^i)^p=T^p-(x^p)^i\in K[T],$$
and the coefficient of the degree $p-1$ term is manifestly zero.

The trace $tr^F_K$ is $K$-linear, so if it vanishes on a basis it vanishes everywhere.

Comment: It seems the converse - finding all finite extensions whose trace vanishes identically - is not obvious as the problem of relating the [trace polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) with the elementary symmetric polynomials